# Call function to display array random list of name

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

[image: code image]

When I call the function, it must display A random person's name.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 1):

You should correct names.length to listof names.length for example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// You only add a paramter when you provide an argument when calling the function, for example if the listOfNames array was outside the function
function whosPaying() {
    let listOfNames = ["Mohamed", "Ahmed", "Farah", "Yusuf", "Dahir"];
    let numberOfPeople = Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfNames.length);

    let randomPerson = listOfNames[numberOfPeople];
    return randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch today!";
}
console.log(whosPaying());
```